# How to call magento 2 validation with using button type is button?

Tags: magento2, jquery, form-validation

I have custom form with 3 fields i.e Name, Email Id, Mobile No.

```
require([
   'jquery',
    'mage/validation'
], function($){

var dataForm = $('#product_addtocart_form');
var ignore = null;

dataForm.mage('validation', {
    ignore: ignore ? ':hidden:not(' + ignore + ')' : ':hidden'
}).find('input:text').attr('autocomplete', 'off');

$('button#estimate').click( function() { //can be replaced with any event
    dataForm.validation('isValid'); //validates form and returns boolean
});
});
```

But function is not validating?

Answer (score 0):

Try following way:

```
if(dataForm.validation() && dataForm.validation('isValid')) {
    $('#product_addtocart_form').submit();
}
```

Comment: I cannot use submit button. I have to validate form using button.